# Why do I get `newline or ;' unexpected error message?

Tags: shell, unix, solaris, ksh, case-statement

```
#!/bin/sh
number=`who | wc -l`
case $number in
1)
    echo "Just you"
    ;;
2)
    echo "Company"
    ;;
3)
    echo "A Crowd"
    ;;
esac
```

I'm trying to learn case statements and I don't understand why I get the specific error message in the question. To be clear the message is **`newline or ;' unexpected**. It doesn't give me a line number for the syntax error. I'm sure there's a simple answer. Thanks in advance. If I can be more clear please let me know.

Comment: `#!/bin/sh` or tag:[tag:ksh] ? & one more thing: The code worked as-is with `/bin/sh` on my ubuntu system. could not try on solaris though.

Comment: I was under the impression it didn't matter. I am in fact using ksh, but when I switch it to #!/bin/sh I still get the error message.

Comment: on solaris, `/bin/sh` is the bourne shell. Apparently it doesn't like case statments. Stay with `/bin/ksh` or `/usr/xpg4/bin/ksh` (if it exists might be the newer `ksh` on your system. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

on Solaris 10, when running your script, I get a $number value with some blank characters before the 1 instead of just 1
I think the $number value needs to be converted to a number.